# Не работает requests

Tags: python-3.x, requests

Я установил Requests 2.25.1 на Python 3.8.5 и написал простой код:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/', verify=False)
print(response.text)
```

И каждый раз мне выдаётся ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\requests.py", line 2, in <module>
    response = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/', verify=False)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'requests' has no attribute 'get' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Подскажите что делать.

Answer (score 0):

Файл называется "requests.py", надо было его всего лишь переименовать.